# slick3.2 codegen for oracle get java.sql.SQLException:invalid column index

Tags: oracle, scala, slick

```
object CodeGen extends App {
  println("Begin to generate cms schma..");

  slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator.main(
    Array("slick.jdbc.OracleProfile", "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:ORCL", 
        "./", 
        "giker.tables.cms",
        "rdcmstest",
        "rdcmstest"
    )     
  )

  println("done!")}
}
```

when I generate code for oracle schema. I got the error:
`java.sql.SQLException：invalid column index`.

What is causing the error? And how to fix the error?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have soled this issue;

because of the sick based on jDK8, but I use Oracle11g.  Ojdbc8 driver is not matching with oracle11g.

when I use oracle12c  and ojdbc8, this issue gone!